# Write to text formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I have a bunch of data in excel that I need to write to txt, that I have to import in an other program. This software has a very specific format, and I have no idea how to create a code that will do it exactly as I need it.

Excel:

[image: Excel]

This is just an example, there are more columns and the actual version and the amount of lines also varies.
In the result text file this should look like this:

txt:

[image: txt]

So it needs the id from line 2, followed by the lines number in brackets then equal sign and the associated name or date in this example.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some looping through cells on the Excel sheet together with some VBA File Input/Output to achieve this. Below is some code that works correctly on the sample data provided, and should get you pointed in the right direction:

```
Sub sExportPersonData()
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim intFile As Integer
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim lngLastCol As Long
    Dim lngRowLoop As Long
    Dim lngColLoop As Long
    Dim strOutput As String
    intFile = FreeFile
    strFile = "J:\downloads\person.txt"
    Open strFile For Output As intFile
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lngLastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lngLastCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For lngRowLoop = 3 To lngLastRow
        For lngColLoop = 2 To lngLastCol
            strOutput = ws.Cells(2, lngColLoop) & "[" & ws.Cells(lngRowLoop, 1) & "]=" & ws.Cells(lngRowLoop, lngColLoop)
            Print #intFile, strOutput
        Next lngColLoop
    Next lngRowLoop
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Close #intFile
    Set ws = Nothing
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "sExportPersonData", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

Regards,